# Error while giving grant to USER from SYS in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, directory, privileges

I am connected to SYSDBA. I want to give access to user **'OFFC'** to read and write on directory `E:\oracle\extract`.So,what I tried is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY EXTRACT_DIR AS 'E:\oracle\extract';
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY EXTRACT_DIR TO OFFC;
GRANT EXECUTE ON UTL_FILE TO OFFC;
```

What i got as error is:

```
Directory created.
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY EXTRACT_DIR TO OFFC
Error at line 2
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-12899: value too large for column "OT"."SCHEMA_AUDIT"."OBJECT_CREATED" (actual: 16, maximum: 15)
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Why is this error coming when I tried to gave the access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have have created the schema level `trigger` which keeps log of the newly created object in `OT.SCHEMA_AUDIT`.

In this table column `OBJECT_CREATED` stores the **schema.object_name** and data type of the column is somewhat `VARCHAR2(15)` or similar.

In your case, you are creating the object `OFFC.EXTRACT_DIR` (length:16) which is causing the issue.

Either disable the `trigger` or increase the Length of the `OBJECT_CREATED` column to around **(257)**

Cheers!!